# How to read data from Google Cloud Storage based on its blobkey?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Early I saved data to blobstore with Files API usage and then read it with the following code:

```
resource = blob_key
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
if blob_info:
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
else:
    self.response.write('Blob entry not found')
```

The documentation says that in many cases I can continue to use blobstore API to work with Google Cloud Storage. But the code above returns `blob_info` equal to `None`.

In accordance with [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob), I should read the data directly from blobstore, but the following code also doesn't work with GCS (`Blob entry not found`), but works well with blobstore files:

```
class BlobstoreServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    if blob_info: # blobstore files
        self.send_blob(blob_info)
    elif blobstore.get(resource): # Google Cloud Storage files
        self.send_blob(resource)
    else:
        self.response.write('Blob entry not found')
```

Comment: Using GCS you don't have a blob_info object. Use self.send_blob(blob_key) with your gs blobkey or download from GCS using the gcs_filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code for downloading blobfiles and GCS files using the Blobstore

You have saved the filename and the blobkey in a db.Model YourFiles entity:

```
your_file = YourFiles.get_by_key_name(key_name)
# blob_ref is a blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
download_url = '/blob_serve/%s?save_as=%s' % (your_file.blob_ref.key(), your_file.file_name)
self.redirect(download_url)   # download using the handler below


class BlobServe(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):          

    def get(self, resource):
        """ use blob_key to download GCS and blobstore blobs """

        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        save_as = self.request.get('save_as')
        self.send_blob(blob_key, save_as=save_as)
```

Comment: Thanks. I store keys as `ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)` (can't modify existing database), `blobstore.BlobKey(blobstore.create_gs_key(...))`  . Could it be a reason of the problem I have?

Comment: Hmm, the problem is with `blobstore.get(resource)` - it returns `None`, when `send_blob` returns correct file. Now I should implement some approach to handle `blob not found` case.

Answer (score 0):

How do you write to Google Cloud Storage? BlobInfo is not created when using 
the [appengine gcs client](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/appengine-gcs-client). For such files you can still create a blob key using [blobstore.create_gs_key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.create_gs_key) but these keys do not have an associated BlobInfo.

Comment: Here is the code I use to save data to Google Cloud Storage - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30349219/604388, `create_gs_key` is used to generate the key (which is passed as `blob_key` to the code given in my questions).

Comment: I see. You use appengine gcs client to write and then you create a BlobKey from the blob string key given by blobstore.create_gs_key. That looks fine. Where is blobstore.get method is coming from?

Comment: Oh, I see. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.get This method also returns a BlobInfo, but clearly there would be no BlobInfo in such a case. To check if file exists you can use the appengine gcs client stats method (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#stat) and expect cloudstorage.NotFoundError when not found (or use https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py#L326)